# The text, ntext, and image data types cannot be compared RowNumber

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

i know that this problem has been resolved many times but after tens forum i cannot find my mistake...

I'm on 2008 SQL Server
Here is my query:

```
Declare @order varchar(MAX) = 'DESC'
Declare @sort varchar(MAX) = 'Description'

SELECT TOP 10 * from ( SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
(ORDER BY 
(CASE WHEN @sort = 'Name' and @order = 'ASC' THEN NAME 
      WHEN @sort = 'URL' and @order = 'ASC' THEN URL
      WHEN @sort = 'Description' and @order = 'ASC' THEN Description       
      END) ASC, 
(CASE WHEN @sort = 'Name' and @order = 'DESC' THEN NAME
      WHEN @sort = 'URL' and @order = 'DESC' THEN URL
      WHEN @sort = 'Description' and @order = 'DESC' THEN Description
      END) DESC) 
AS RowNum FROM Application) AS MyDerivedTable WHERE MyDerivedTable.RowNum BETWEEN 0 AND 10
```

And the error:

> "The text, ntext, and image data types cannot be compared or sorted,
>   except when using IS NULL or LIKE operator"

I also tried to replace varchar by nvarchar but it doesnt worked.

Thanks for help

Comment: [Please remove text, ntext, and image data types from your projects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/ntext-text-and-image-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: one of your columns will be one of those types, please share the DDL of the table

Comment: You were right, i had 'URL' as a 'text' in my table, thanks ;)

Comment: Please avoid editing your question with the solution. Instead, post it as an answer and accept it once the time limit is done. That way, other people will know that the problem is solved directly from the questions list.

Answer (score 0):

A `case` expression returns a single type.  I would recommend that you rewrite the `order by` using separate expressions:

```
ORDER BY (CASE WHEN @sort = 'Name' and @order = 'ASC' THEN NAME END) ASC,
         (CASE WHEN @sort = 'URL' and @order = 'ASC' THEN URL END) ASC,
         (CASE WHEN @sort = 'Description' and @order = 'ASC' THEN Description END) ASC, 
         (CASE WHEN @sort = 'Name' and @order = 'DESC' THEN NAME END) DESC,
         (CASE WHEN @sort = 'URL' and @order = 'DESC' THEN URL END) DESC,
         (CASE WHEN @sort = 'Description' and @order = 'DESC' THEN Description END) DESC
```

I'm not sure if this will fix your particular problem, which seems due to arcane types being used for certain columns.  However, this fixes most of the problems that arise from using a single `case` expression with mixed types.

Presumably, you are using `text` columns.  This type has been deprecated, so you should not use it.  I would strongly recommend that you change the type to `varchar(max)` or `nvarchar(max)`.

Comment: It's not a conversion error, it's a sorting error. They'd still get the same error from at least two of these separate `CASE` expressions.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED ! I Had a 'URL' as type 'text' in my Table definition, I replaced it by nvarchar. Thank you